# String assignment mystic issue. Variable name affects behavior

Tags: c#, .net, variable-assignment, code-contracts

I have the following code inside a method:

```
string username = (string)context["UserName"];

string un = (string)context["UserName"];
```

The problem is that the first string "username" is not assigned, while the second does.

To make it more strange, when I have stopped the debugging after the first line and copied the line to the Immediate window, dropping the varible type delaration, it was assigned succesfully.

I have made rebuild all and checked project properties which seems to be OK.

The `context` variable is a `System.Configuration.SettingsContext`, which is a hash table. To be more specific, I'm implementing a profile provider, the `GetPropertyValues` method.

I am using VS 2012 and .NET 4.5

**EDIT:**

I am using code contract in my project, which uses compile time code injection for runtime checking. I disabled it and all is working well. I'll try to remove contracts one by one to find which one is causing the problem.

Comment: Unlikely to be the variable name. Did you try swapping the order of the assignments?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another `username` variable defined elsewhere that is in scope?

Comment: @Douglas Not only that. I have also tried to assign value to an object and to the string after that, but no luck.

Comment: Provide the context (class, method, major library). Right now it's not even clear if these are local vars or fields.

Comment: @Oded Intellisence gives nothing

Comment: It's not the variable name unless you are shadowing a class level variable and then attempting to read the result of the assignment from another method.  Please create a small reproducible code sample, there is no way we can solve this problem for you given what information you have provided.  And forget intellisense, you're just adding a layer of confusion into your troubleshooting.

Comment: @aikixd: I meant that the variable name does not make a difference. If you name your first variable "un" and your second variable "username", then I'm confident that "username" would get assigned (assuming your behaviour is consistent and not consequent of a threading issue).

Comment: Try to assign to `/* string */ username`

Comment: @Ed-S There are no fields I have defined for that class with this name. The class is a deriviation from .NET, so I don't know whether it is defined there. But I can assign the variable from within the Immediate window and after that the application executes fine. I'll try to reproduce it in test project.

Comment: @Henk-Holterman Does not compile.

Comment: *"The class is a deriviation from .NET"* - I have no idea what that means.

Comment: @Ed-S I have mispelled. The class is a deriviation from .NET class. I have also looked at the .NET disassembley and found no fields with this name in ancestor classes.

Comment: Wait... so you have decompiled a type defined in the library and are using that to create this example?  I have no idea how to interpret this problem anymore.

Comment: @Ed-S Ofcource not. I have used the ILSpy to look inside.

Comment: The CC angle makes it much more relevant, and more wanting of a small reproducable case.

Comment: To the people wondering: it is indeed a bug in Code Contracts, and I have reproduced it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is similar to a Code Contracts bug I saw before. I wrote something about it [here a few months back](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/codecontracts/thread/56d8e382-1330-492d-919a-e936f1e7096f/). If you have this bug, you probably also have a lambda or LINQ expression in your method that uses `username`.

For future reference, this is the bug I saw:

> I had in the same method a lambda expression capturing a local variable, lets say `values`, and a Contract.Requires() expression checking something completely unrelated. While debugging that method, the debugger shows in Locals the variable `values` twice, and reports the value of `values` always as null even when this is clearly not the case.
>
> To reproduce:
>
> ```
>   static void Reproduction(string argument)
>   {
>       Contract.Requires(argument != null); // <-- (1)
>
>       int[] values = new int[1];
>       Debug.Assert(values != null);
>
>       Func<int, bool> d = i => values[i] >= 0; // <-- (2)
>
>       Console.WriteLine(values);
>   }
> ```
>
> Put a breakpoint somewhere in this method after the assignment to `values` and ensure that the method gets called. When the debugger hits the breakpoint, look at the Locals list of Visual Studio for the duplicate variable. Hover the mouse over `values` to find that it gets reported as being `null`, something which is clearly not the case.
>
> The problem disappears when removing either the contract (1) or the line with the lambda (2).

Comment: Yes, that is the case. I use this variable in linq expression.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating and desabling contracts I found that the problem appears only when runtime contracts checking is enabled and this contract appears:

```
Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyValueCollection>() != null);
```

If I delete this line, the code works, so it looks like code contracts bug, though I couldn't recreate it on a test project.